# このため、東京や大阪、京都以外にも泊まる人が増えるように、いろいろな観光地を紹介していくことにしています

Tags: grammar

> このため、東京や大阪、京都以外にも泊まる人が増えるように、いろいろな観光地を紹介していくことにしています。([source](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011218521000/k10011218521000.html))

My attempt at translation:

> To achieve this (or: because of that?), it was decided that they (will?) present various tourist attractions, except for Tokyo, Osaka and Kyoto, so that the number of people taking sleepovers increases.

First, I translated both ように and ため in a final sense ("they did X, so that..."/"...in order to..." etc.). In previous questions about ように it often happened that ように didn't represent this, but here I wouldn't know which else case could apply. It seems odd though that there are two final clauses "sandwiched" into this sentence.

Second, 東京や大阪、京都 by itself is already a bit confusing, because first there is a connective や, and then 京都 follows without any particle. I guess it belongs to the other two, however, I'm not sure because I didn't encounter this case so far and I could also imagine that concerning 以外, maybe 京都 alone is the exception. However, in this case I wouldn't know how to implement the other two 東京や大阪 because there wouldn't be any particle embedding them into the syntax of the sentence.

And finally, is 紹介する used in the meaning of some form of publicity/marketing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation attempt is okay except for the 東京や大阪、京都以外にも part. Don't ignore に and も. It adverbially modifies 泊まる and means "(to put up) **also in** places other than Tokyo, Osaka or Kyoto." Your translation would be much more natural just by moving this part right after "sleepover".

「東京や大阪、京都」 is a natural way to list things in Japanese. It could have been 「東京、大阪や京都」 (like you say this in English) or 「東京や大阪や京都」 (although this looks slightly clumsy). After all, the usage of comma is less strict in Japanese, as you may already know.

Your understanding of ように is perfect. It means "so that ～" or "in order to ～" here.

I think this このため is closer to "because of this", and can be simply translated as "Therefore."

Oh, where did "health" come from? Check the meaning of 観光地.

Comment: Oh yeah, that definitely was a typo, although I don't know how I managed to type it correctly in this post, while typing it incorrectly into jisho when searching for the meaning...^^ Thanks :)

Comment: Following your answer, does this mean that:
東京や大阪、京都以外にも[...]いろいろな観光地を紹介していくことにしています can be parsed as one unit?

I would then translate the full sentence to:
"Because of that, it was decided that they present tourist attractions also in places other than Tokyo, Oosaka and Kyoto, [so that the number of people taking sleepovers increases]."

Comment: @Narktor I think, and I'm sorry if I'm incorrect, that your question would be equivalent to asking if the も in 東京…以外にも is interpreted as replacing は thus making the expression a topic of discussion rather than an adverbial modifier of 泊まる. I'd also be interested to know if that is true.

Comment: By the way, @Narktor, this is an English usage issue, but "sleepover" has a specific meaning in (American) English which is not the meaning you intend. See: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sleepover ; in the present-day US, only meaning 1 is commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this このため is "in order to achieve [the increase in accommodations discussed in the previous sentence]".

> 東京や大阪、京都以外にも泊まる人

"People staying outside places like Tokyo, Osaka, and Kyoto..."

> が増えるように

"...in order to increase [the number of those people]..."

> いろいろな観光地を紹介していくことにしています。

"...we have decided to continue introducing various tourist attractions."

There is no mention of "health resorts." Perhaps you were confusing "観光" and "健康"?

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this.

Comment: ^（ダウンボートしたの私じゃないですけど、）「このため」を in order to achieve って書いたからですかね・・

Comment: I didn't downvote either but I suppose it might be because "outside places like..." sounds like "the immediate surroundings of Tokyo...". That implication is not in the Japanese which is simply stating anywhere but Tokyo...

Comment: I think Chocolate is right; I assumed the wrong ため.